# C++: Error: Unable to create variable object

Tags: c++

I have a simple method:

```
std::vector<string> start()
{
    std::vector<std::string> deletedFiles; // << error appeared at this declaration
}
```

Error: Unable to create variable object

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This similar program compiles without a hitch:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> start()
{
    std::vector<std::string> deletedFiles;
    return deletedFiles;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> deletedFiles = start();
    return 0;
}
```

Please double check your `#include`s and your `std::`s. You might want to add `std::` to `string` in your return type.

Comment: hi, I have already included vector and string and return but it is till giving that error. thanks!

Comment: @JoesyXHN: It would be great if you could post a complete source file that exhibited the problem along with the command you use to compile it. Then we might be able to reproduce your problem locally.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, really. The error will be somewhere else. For instance, there's a missing return statement in the function, and you're missing `#include`'s, but that's probably code you snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've missed a namespace prefix...

```
std::vector<string> start()
```

Should it be this?

```
 std::vector<std::string> start()
```